# Why does geolocation not work on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am trying to get the location of the user with HTML5 `geolocation`.
On Desktop it works great, but on all my mobile devices (Samsung note, Samsung galaxy S4 And Iphone 6) its not working and not showing the `error` object.

this is my code:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var coor = position.coords.longitude+", "+position.coords.latitude;
    alert(coor);
}
function errorPosition(error) {
    alert(error);
}
function toggleGeolocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition,errorPosition);
}
```

It asks to get permission for geolocation and I click allow (gps is working). What could be the problem?

I am using Google Chrome on all devices.

Comment: It's working for me on my iPhone 5 running iOS 8.1 on Safari and Chrome, as well as on my Galaxy Tab 4 Kit-Kat in Chrome and the Android stock browser. This code isn't what's causing this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this code, it should work.

```
var successHandler = function(position) { 
alert(position.coords.latitude); 
alert(position.coords.longitude); 
}; 

var errorHandler = function (errorObj) { 
alert(errorObj.code + ": " + errorObj.message); 

alert("something wrong take this lat " + 26.0546106 ); 
alert("something wrong take this lng " +-98.3939791); 

}; 

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 
successHandler, errorHandler, 
{enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 10000});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i still cant get error msg, I added alert msg like this:
          function initializeGeo() {
              if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
                  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorCallback);
                  alert("OK");
              } else {
                  alert('Geolocation is not supported');
              }
          }
and I am getting this msg, its means Geolocation is supported but the row:
                  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorCallback);
do nothing...

Comment: I have beed added alert msg after the row that calls to getCurrentPosition, and I can see the alert msg but cant see the result of getCurrentPosition

Comment: Then what? Is it solved or not?
`Geolocation` is available in **secure contexts**. So if you are not serving the app without `https` it will not work unless the origin is `localhost` in almost all supporting browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Navigator will only work on Android on https websites.
Here is an example that will not show an error if using http, but will work fine on https (from https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to make it work on localhost in android chrome?

Comment: @RanjitKumar You could make a self signed certificate. Let's Encrypt has some instructions on how to do it yourself: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Answer (score 1):

Hi @jordan I was facing the same what i did is

First make sure you have updated chrome browser on your device.

1. started Location service of mobile device 1st
2. called the getLocation() function onLoad

By doing this it asked me about permission and worked out well.

Comment: This is actually the simple and correct answer, i tried using window.onload = getLocation; and the getLocation function i invoke without parentheses but with parentheses it work for me on mobile device as well. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // google geolocation
    googleMap: function(func){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            //get location
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var coords = position.coords;
                lat = coords.latitude;
                lng = coords.longitude;

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode( {'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        var time = Date.parse(new Date());
                        var resultArr = results[0].address_components, address = "" ,LocationName = "",province = "",city = "",district = "";

                        for (var i = 0; i < resultArr.length; i++) {
                            var type = resultArr[i].types[0] ? resultArr[i].types[0] : 0;
                            if (type && type == "street_number") {
                                LocationName = resultArr[i].short_name;
                            }
                            if (type && type == "route") {
                                address = address + resultArr[i].short_name;
                            }
                            if (type && type == "political") {
                                district = resultArr[i].short_name;
                            }
                            if (type && type == "locality") {
                                city = resultArr[i].short_name;
                            }
                            if (type && type == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                                province = resultArr[i].short_name;
                            }
                        }

                        var data = {'name': LocationName + ' ' + address, 'address': address, 'lng': lng, 'lat': lat, 'province': province, 'city': city, 'district': district};
                        func(data);

                    } else {
                        func();
                        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                });

            }, function getError(error){
                func();
                switch(error.code){
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert(langData['siteConfig'][22][100]);
                        break;
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        alert(langData['siteConfig'][22][101]);
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert(langData['siteConfig'][22][102]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            })
        }else {
            func();
            alert(langData['waimai'][3][72])
        }
    },
```

```html
h5: function(func){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            if ("function" == typeof func) {
                h5LocationInit.fn = func
            }
            window.touchH5LocationCallback = function(f, g) {
                if(f == null){
                    HN_Location.getLocationByGeocoding(g);
                }else{
                    // getLocationError(f);
                    HN_Location.init(func, true);
                }
                $("#touchH5LocationIframe").remove();
            },
                $('<iframe src="javascript:(function(){ window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){parent && parent.touchH5LocationCallback && parent.touchH5LocationCallback(null,position);}, function(err){parent && parent.touchH5LocationCallback && parent.touchH5LocationCallback(err);}, {enableHighAccuracy: 1, maximumAge: 10000, timeout: 5000});})()" style="display:none;" id="touchH5LocationIframe" ></iframe>').appendTo("body")
        } else {
            // var r = {
            //   tips: "broswer not supported"
            // };
            // "function" == typeof func ? func(r) : "[object Object]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(func) && func.fn && func.fn(r)
            HN_Location.init(func, true);
        }
    },
```

I totally same with your case. Finding the answer so hard ...

Comment: How about adding some explaing text to your answer - to make it simpler to udnerstand your solution?

Comment: um , my current situation is the geolocation can call at pc broswer , but it not working on phone broswer. The location permission request will pop out but it wont have any response after that ...